# iOS Simulator and GKVoiceChat

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator, gamekit, avaudiosession

This is a pretty simple question, but I can't seem to find the answer in Apple's API documentation. I was just wondering if the iOS Simulator supports a GKVoiceChat session? It seems that I have everything correctly set up in my code, but no voice is transmitted.

For reference, here is the code I've implemented:

*Here I set up the AVAudioSession as required*

> audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
>       [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
>       [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];

*Here I create a voice channel and supposedly start it by setting it to active*

> ```
> gameVoice = [SharedMatch voiceChatWithName:@"allPlayers"];
> [gameVoice start];
> [gameVoice setActive:YES];
> ```

I also have implemented the playerVoiceChatStateDidChangeHandler but I think any truly relavent information is detailed above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested this specific API, but I suspect it does not as input does not work for many higher level audio APIs in the sim.